# Print contents of datatable in HTML/Test format including headers and totals using C#.net 2.0

Tags: html, sql-server, ado.net, c#-2.0

I have an application to generate dynamic reports using dynamic SQLs. The results of the query will be stored in datatables. I need a function to take the datatable and column width as input and print report in HTML/Text format. The function should identify correct data type of  datacolumn and format it as per the data type.

I'll write a query like this and fetch the values into data table:
SELECT [ID]
      ,[AccountName] AS [Account Name]
      ,[TransDate] AS [Trans Date]
      ,[Amount]
  FROM [AccountsTable]

The following is the result set in datatable:
**ID    [Account Name]  [Trans Date]    [Amount]**
656 Sales Account   14-Apr-2003 13500.00
657 Purchase Account    15-Apr-2003 2000.00
658 Cheque Account  15-Apr-2003 5250.00
659 Sales Account   16-Apr-2003 8000.00
660 Cheque Account  17-Apr-2003 6500.00
661 Purchase Account    18-Apr-2003 1000.00
662 Trade Account   18-Apr-2003 10250.00
663 Discount Account    19-Apr-2003 500.00
Totals:                                        47000.00

I would like to print these values into HTML File as shown above. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //make your own table here, whathever way you like ie get it from database
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("col2");
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "2" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "5", "6" });

        RenderTable(dt, 100);
    }

    private void RenderTable(DataTable datatable, int column_width)
    {
        Table table = new Table();

        //add header to your table 
        TableHeaderRow header = new TableHeaderRow();

        foreach (DataColumn dcol in datatable.Columns)
        {
            TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
            cell.Width = column_width;

            Label headlbl = new Label();
            headlbl.Text = dcol.ColumnName;

            cell.Controls.Add(headlbl);
            header.Controls.Add(cell);
        }

        table.Controls.Add(header);

        //fill with data
        foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                TableCell td = new TableCell();
                td.Width = column_width;

                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = Convert(row[i], datatable.Columns[i].DataType);

                td.Controls.Add(label);
                tr.Controls.Add(td);
            }

            table.Controls.Add(tr);
        }

        //add other rows here ie totals

        Page.Controls.Add(table);

    }

    private string Convert(object val, Type type)
    {
        //do whatever you want with format of your cells
        return val.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Dear @Silx, nice answer. I need to print the contents of datatable from Windows forms application. I'm very sorry for not mentionining that. Kindly provide the solution to print the datatable in Windows forms application. Thanks...

Comment: html is not a windows forms aplication language :/ you want to save it as HTML file from winforms app ??

Comment: I want to save the result as HTML file. Pls help.